# Hugo website not rendering in Github pages

Tags: frontend, github-pages, hugo

I am trying to correctly visualize my portfolio on Github pages after deploy with no success and I am running out of ideas for what the problem might be.

Problem:

- The live page either shows " This site is open source. [Improve this page]" if my index.html is inside of “layouts” folder (as it is originally in the theme) or it shows the raw index.html file - if I place index.html in the root.

Facts:

1. I am able to run the website without any problem locally, and it renders the expected result.
2. I have followed the suggestions of having “/” as baseURL.
3. I have tried placing the index.html file in the root directory (seems the logic structure to adopt)
4. Inspecting the index page, I get no errors on the console whatsoever when index.html is placed in the root and shows live (as raw html).
5. I get no deployment errors (I follow the builds in Github’s deployment log).
6. I am able to access css, js and images folder publicly and see the content with the live url.

I am new to Hugo and I have no idea what I can do more, any help would be much appreciated!
My repository is:
https://github.com/anaritagomes/anaritagomes.github.io

I am using Hugo's "UILite" theme:
https://themes.gohugo.io/hugo-uilite/

Comment: How are you actually publishing the site? You can't just drop the sources into a github repository and have it work: you need to render the pages (run `hugo` to create the `public` directory) and then publish that directory to e.g. your `gh-pages` branch (which you could do either manually or automate via GitHub Actions). if you do that, [it seems to work just fine](http://oddbit.com/anaritagomes.github.io/).

Comment: See e.g. [these docs from the Hugo project](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/)

Answer (score 2):

A lot of stuff with Hugo isn't written for beginners and a lot of people have the same problem.

In simple terms, when you run Hugo on your computer it will set up a website that you can access through Hugo (i.e. on localhost:1313). It's a bit like when you create a file in Photoshop it saves it as a PSD file that you can access through Photoshop but if you want to actually put that file on the internet you'll export it as a PNG file or a JPG (or whatever).

Well in Hugo this "export" step also has to be done. The command to do this is just "hugo -D". This will create a folder called "public" and it's the contents of this folder that you send to Github pages.

Comment: The `-D` isn't needed unless you also want to publish content that is still in draft state.